# How to properly define class for a random forest model?

Tags: python, class, scikit-learn, random-forest, production

I am using a random forest that I trained and saved. I want to create a class that consumes that model and gives prediction.
I am new to classes and I did as below:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
import os
import joblib

model_path = r"the path of the model"
model =  joblib.load(os.path.join(model_path,'rf.pkl'))

class MODEL_RF(RandomForestClassifier):

 def load_model(self):
        self.model = model

 def get_pred(self, df):
        validation_features = np.array(df)
        self.model = self.load_model()
        pred = self.predict(validation_features)
        predict_prob = self.predict_proba(validation_features)
        return pred,predict_prob

model_m = MODEL_RF()
prediction, probs = model_m.get_pred(input_df)
```

However,
I am getting error as below:

```
    raise NotFittedError(msg % {"name": type(estimator).__name__})
sklearn.exceptions.NotFittedError: This MODEL_RF instance is not fitted yet. Call 'fit' with appropriate arguments before using this estimator.
```

Comment: Always provide the full error traceback; it contains valuable debugging information.

Answer (score 1):

The error arises because your class inherits from `RandomForestClassifier`, so that the line `self.predict` is trying to call the sklearn-defined `predict` method, but your wrapper class contains none of the fitted information about a random forest; all of that is **contained in** the *attribute* `self.model`, but not available as attributes of your class directly.

I'm not convinced there's a reason to create a new class just to wrap a pickled sklearn model.  Just put the code from `get_pred` directly into the script.  If you do have a good reason, then I would advise to skip inheriting from `RandomForestClassifier`, and instead just always call `self.model.predict`, `self.model.predict_proba`, etc.